# Python ctypes: how to pass ctypes array to DLL?

Tags: python, ctypes

Calling a *dll* from Python using *ctypes*, I want to pass a ctypes array to the *dll*.  Here is the Python code:

```
ReturnVec = ctypes.c_float * len(arrA)
t = type(ReturnVec)
hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL(r"C:/Temp2/Test_Project_3B/Std_Math_Formulas.dll")
SimpleTest = hllDll.SimpleTest
SimpleTest.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)]
SimpleTest.restype = ctypes.c_void_p
retvar = SimpleTest(ctypes.byref(pvarr),ctypes.c_float(ReturnVec))
```

The final line throws the error:

> "TypeError: must be real number, not _ctypes.PyCArrayType."

The variable `t` shows that its type is `ctypes.PyCArrayType`.  The variable `ReturnVec` shows that its type is `c_floatarray_1000` (where `1000` is the length of the array).

I try to cast it to a `float`:

```
aq = ctypes.cast(ReturnVec, ctypes.c_float)
```

but it returns:

> "<class 'TypeError'>: wrong type"

I try to cast it to a pointer, I get the same thing:

```
floatPtr = ctypes.cast(ReturnVec, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float))
```

I've researched this at length, and there are many threads on this issue, but none described my situation.

Answer (score 1):

`ReturnVec` is a *type*, hence the "must be a real number" error.  You need an instance of the type:

```
ReturnVecInstance = ReturnVec()
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is the answer to my question above:

SimpleTest = hllDll.SimpleTest

SimpleTest.argtypes = [ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p]
SimpleTest.restype = ctypes.c_int64

retvar = SimpleTest(ctypes.byref(pvarr),ctypes.byref(arrA))

Comment: This isn't a complete answer.  What is `pvarr` and `arrA` (which weren't defined in the question either)?